# RF Interference and Metal Enclosure

Tags: emc, troubleshooting, faraday-cage

We have a product (optical detector), one client had an issue with false alarms due to their radios they use on site.

Did some modifications, added a ferrite bead to the cable and put a driven guard shield around the sensor. With the PCB with these mods, and no housing just lying on my workbench, it won't trigger by radio short of putting the antenna right beside it. They are unlikely to do this, so this looks great.

However, I put it back into the body of the detector it appears to negate these changes entirely. It false alarms again at range again.

My question is why would this occur? I went so far as to make sure all the metal plates and the body were stripped of paint on the joints. With only three openings (much smaller then the 150 MHz wavelength) on the unit for the sensor window, pot knob, and cable grip.

Shouldn't this be a Faraday cage and block everything? I tried grounding the body to 0 VDC and Earth or both, no effect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How big a box are we talking? Any chance you are forming some kind of resonant cavity, and even the smallest amount of 150MHz signal is enough to get oscillation started?

Comment: Joren, the internal volume is 1" x 2.5" x 2.5"
Unless I did the math wrong, I don't think it should be resonate near the 150 Mhz mark (though I just realized I didn't consider harmonics).

Comment: Is the metal enclosure mounted on a metal object which is either earthed or would create a much larger antenna?

Comment: Right now it is not mounted, sitting on a workbench with a particle board top. In the field it would be mounted to a metal structure overlooking a conveyor.

Comment: The rf sensitive part: Is it the detector box or the system X that collects the alarms from different detectors?

Comment: The detectors are independent and connect to a PLC, the end user decides what they want to do with a detection event/signal. It's a pyro sensor in the unit (looking for burning material), some filter/amps, window comparator, then a microcontroller, and the output is through some reed relays. Not much too it. I wouldn't be allowed to post a schematic, but there isn't exactly anything novel here.

Comment: Have you looked at conducted emissions at the site? It might also be worth it to try different experiments... Make sure its radio and make sure its not conducted noise even though you put a ferrite on the box I would also suspect that. Make sure you can trigger the problem with a radio.

Comment: They are half a globe away. Travel, with our lack of tools, is unlikely to produce anything. It's quite observable that it's when they activate their walkie-talkie. Using a walkie-talkie here at the same frequency does the same thing.